# How can i delete and deselect multiple items at once using an iron-list for Polymer 1.2.4?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have an iron-list where i want to provide the option to select multiple items and delete them at once. This is my `iron-list` with `multi-selection`:

```
<iron-list items="[[users]]" as="user" selected-items="{{selectedUsers}}" multi-selection>
...
</iron-list>
```

I have used forEach loop for selected items array:

```
_deleteSelected: function(e) {
    this.selectedUsers.forEach(function(user) {
        var index = this.users.indexOf(user);
          if (index != -1) {
              this.splice('users', index, 1);
          }          
    }, this);

    this.querySelector('iron-list').clearSelection();

    console.log(this.selectedUsers);
}
```

In every loop i calculate the item's index in the main items array and then i use `this.splice('items', index, 1)` to delete it. After the loop ends i use this `this.querySelector('iron-list').clearSelection();` to clear my selections and move on. But my iteration fails since the loop seems to run only once no matter how many items i have selected. If i select only one item then it is removed correctly and the list gets refreshed. But sth strange happens here since the item that now has the same index as the one i have just removed appears to be checked. For example i have three items, i select the second one and remove it. Now second is the item which was third before but appears to be checked with no reason while the selected items array is empty as wanted. I guess those happen because of the arrays reference Polymer uses. How can i tackle this behaviour in iron-list selections? Is there a way to use just splice without having to clear the selected items array?

My full component example is [here](http://jsbin.com/wuhuco/edit?html,output).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is that you run the for loop on

```
this.selectedUsers
```

so you run on this array and then delete user from this.users so now the iron set this.selectedUsers to be [] because  the list is new.

My solution is to write

```
 this.selectedUsers.slice().forEach(function(user) { ...
```

thus it creates new array and then this array does not changes because the this.users changed

Comment: Hmm, here if one item is removed the item with same index as the deleted one with no reason appears to be the checked.

Comment: yes this is true. because you didnt bind the selected to the check box.

you have or to uncheck it by yourself or make a bind.

Comment: Oh thank you! If i use `this.selectedUsers.slice()` to loop through and change the items inside `iron-list` to `<paper-checkbox checked="[[selected]]" on-tap="_selectItem"></paper-checkbox> [[user.name]]` taking advantage of `selected` it seems to work fine. Next step is to apply sorted and filtered items.

Answer (score 0):

How about -

this.users = this.users.filter(function(u){
    return (this.selectedUsers.indexOf(u) == -1);
});

Comment: This removes selected items and the list gets refreshed. The issue is that i end up having selected items with no reason those which now have same index as the ones just removed.